# Unknown vEthernet adapters

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine, ethernet, hyper-v, windows-11

I have Windows 11 (version 10.0.22000) desktop with Hyper-V host which has 2 virtual switches: `Default` and `external-switch-1` - both based on `Ethernet` physical card. Not `Ethernet 2`

There are 2 VMs, both using `external-switch-1`.

I can see 2 adapters (*with question mark*) that I dont understand where they came from (the Hyper-V was installed cleanly and one external switch added, I didnt do anything else).

*Is it safe to delete these (`vEthernet (vEthernet (exte)`, `vEthernet (Ethernet 2)`, `vEthernet (WiFi)`) ?*

*How do I delete them (they arent in Hyper-V Virtual Switch Manager) ?*

**EDIT: More precisely:

I do NOT want my VMs using other adapters than the one I set up. Not Wifi and not Realtek.

How to ensure that?
**

*powershell*

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetAdapter | Select name

name
----
WiFi
vEthernet (WiFi)
Bluetooth Network Connection
Ethernet 2
vEthernet (Default Switch)
vEthernet (vEthernet (exte)      ?
vEthernet (Ethernet 2)           ?
vEthernet (external-switch-1)
Ethernet
```

*control panel*

[image: Control Panel]

*Device Manager (**with** Show Hidden Devices)*

[image: Device Manager]

Answer (score 1):

According to your screen shot, what you see appears to be normal.

You have Bluetooth, 2 Wired Ethernet (different physical NIC brands), Wireless (not connected).  That is in your screen shot.

Then you have your Hyper-V connection. These also show up in the Hidden Devices.

Are you using both the Intel wired connection (Intel 1211) and the Realtek PCIe connection?  Assuming you are using both adapters, this contributes to the extra NICs showing up in the adapter list.

There is no need to delete Hyper-V adapters and you should not.

Comment: I use both. Intel - for VMs and Realtek for the host. Wifi is a backup (not connected), Bluetooth (turned off).. The bottom line - I only need `external-switch-1` and I cannot delete `Default Switch` but I dont need the 3 others `vEthernets` - is it safe to delete them and then how?

Comment: I would not delete the Hyper-V connections and you have extra connections by having extra hardware. So what you have is normal and just leave Hyper-V be.