# Why ipconfig shows NICs (Hyper-V) which arent in device manager and how to delete them?

Tags: windows-10, networking, ethernet, hyper-v, windows-11

when I run `ipconfig /all` I see adapters (created by Hyper-V) but they are NOT in device manager (Show hidden devices is ON) and they are NOT in Hyper-V virtual switch manager.

I have 2 VMs. They are stopped atm and both have `vEthernet (external-switch-1)` for NIC.

Of all 4 sources the "unwanted" NICs are only in ipconfig.

**Why and how to delete the following adapters?**

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Ethernet 2.5GbE) - Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (vEthernet (exte) - Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
```

Here are illustrations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
C:\>ipconfig.exe /all                                                                                                                                                               
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : XX
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2.5GbE:

   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe 2.5GbE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 24-4B-FE-59-D3-08

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (external-switch-1):

   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 24-4B-FE-59-D3-07

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Ethernet 2.5GbE):

   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-B3-D2-A9 

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):
 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-28-80-22

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (vEthernet (exte):

   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-DA-81-7F
```

**EDIT:** I found another place which has these phantom adapters:

Poweshell

```
> Get-NetAdapter | Select name

name
----
WiFi
vEthernet (vEthernet (exte)
Bluetooth Network Connection
Ethernet 2.5GbE
vEthernet (Ethernet 2.5GbE)
vEthernet (Default Switch)
vEthernet (external-switch-1)
Ethernet
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unknown vEthernet adapters](https://superuser.com/questions/1719983/unknown-vethernet-adapters)

Comment: no. its my question and it describes different problem

Comment: You have 2 real NICs.  What is different here?

Comment: i want ensure there is no unnecessary latency because Hyper-V screwing things.. I want these 2 gone.

Comment: I am fairly sure this issue arises because you have two physical Network Cards, Same issue as before.

Comment: it doesnt matter how many cards - why these entries are in ipconfig but nowehere else? and how to rid of them - these are not real.

Comment: What leads you to believe these virtual adapters are a problem or causing "latency"?

Comment: @BoppityBop Do you have the Windows Feature "Windows Sandbox" installed/enabled?

Comment: I just found it that it was Sandbox! sorry didnt see your comment as I was rebooting non-stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the adapters arent (or not entirely) because of Hyper-V. They were created by the "Sandbox" feature.

What I did:

1. Uninstalled Hyper-V : no effect
2. Disabled DNS Cache  : vEthernet gone
3. Re-enabled DNS Cache: they are back
4. Uninstalled Sandbox : vEthernet gone
5. Installed Hyper-V   : unwanted vEthernet devices are gone

Each step with a reboot.
*In hindsight - I am not sure whether step 1 and 2 were of any use.*

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have done too much in your answer, that disabling the
Windows Sandbox was enough.

The following is my
[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1584964/8672)
that worked for that poster.

---

This post resumes the results of the study done by one poster:
[Windows Sandbox on Win10 2004 now creates vEthernet interface for every physical NIC?](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d443bc7f-4cf4-4a8a-9ae3-4fd359c37849/windows-sandbox-on-win10-2004-now-creates-vethernet-interface-for-every-physical-nic?forum=win10itprovirt)

His conclusion is that these new virtual switches were related to the feature of
Windows Sandbox. Uninstalling the Sandbox in
*Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off*
and reboot removes these switches. If you wish to keep Windows Sandbox,
you will need to also keep the switches.

I reproduce below his account:

> I updated to Win10 2004 (Build 19041.208 as of this writing) and I've
> noticed that on my system with Hyper-V and Windows Sandbox installed,
> I now have an auto-created vEthernet interface for every physical
> Ethernet interface on my system.  Each one is named "vEthernet
> (Physical interface name)".  This is occurring despite that fact that
> only virtual switch I have on my host system is the Default Switch.
>
> When I run "Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS", I see multiple
> adapters named "Container NIC xxxxxx", each showing as attached to the
> Default Switch.
>
> All of these vEthernet interfaces have auto-assigned 172.x.x.x IP
> addresses.  They cannot be deleted in Network Connections (option is
> grayed out) and if I use Device Manager to uninstall the actual
> Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet adapter device associated with these
> interfaces, they reappear after rebooting.  This behavior persisted
> even after I completely uninstalled Hyper-V, but when I reinstalled it
> and instead uninstalled Windows Sandbox, the vEthernet interfaces all
> disappeared, except for the one associated with the Default Switch,
> which I expected to remain. And at that point, running
> "Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS" returned only one result.